# IndexOf for char array ignoring casing

Tags: c#, arrays, search, indexof

I'm developing a pdf file viewer. A pdf file stores it characters in bytes and a pdf file can have several megabytes. Using strings for this scenario is a bad idea, because the storage space of a string cannot be reused for another string. Therefor I store these pdf bytes in a char array. When reading the next big pdf file, I can reuse the char array.

Now I need to support a search functionality, so that the user can find a certain text in this huge file. When I am searching, I usually don't want to have to enter proper upper and lower case letters, I might even not remember the correct casing, meaning the search should succeed regardless of casing. When using

```cs
string.IndexOf(String, StringComparison)
```

one can chose `InvariantCultureIgnoreCase` to get both upper and lower case matches.

However, converting the megabyte char array into an equally big string is a bad idea.

Unfortunately, `IndexOf` for an `Array` is not helpful:

```cs
public static int IndexOf<T> (T[] array, T value);
```

This allows to search for only 1 char in a char array and does also not support `IgnoreCase`, which obviously wouldn't make sense for other arrays, like an integer array.

**So the question is:**
Which method can be used from DotNet to search a string in a character array.

**Please read this before marking this question as dupplicate**
I am aware that there are already similar questions regarding searching. But the ones I have seen all convert the character array in one way or another into a string, which I definitely not want.

Also note that many of those solutions don't support ignoring the casing. The solution should also handle exotic Unicodes correctly.

And last but not least, best would be an existing method from DotNet.

Comment: The reason why this doesn't exist for `char` is because you usually need the whole string to decide how to compare, for example whether to ignore diacritics or unnormalized characters.

Answer (score 2):

I came to the conclusion that I need to implement my own IndexOf method for character arrays. However, programming that proved rather challenging, so I checked in the DotNet source code how [string.IndexOf](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/String.Searching.cs,7d6aed52d875ec59) is doing it.

It's a bit confusing because one method is calling another which calls another, each doing not much. Finally, one arrives at:

```cs
public unsafe int IndexOf(ReadOnlySpan<char> source, ReadOnlySpan<char> value,
                          CompareOptions options = CompareOptions.None)
```

Lo and behold, that was exactly the functionality I was looking for, because it is very easy to convert a `char[]` into a `ReadOnlySpan<char>`. This method belongs to the `CompareInfo` class. To call it, one has to write something like this:

```cs
var index = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.CompareInfo.IndexOf(bigCharArray,
                                          searchString, CompareOptions.IgnoreCase);
```